# How do I /setblock a hanging soul lantern?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I do the command:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ lantern 1
```

the block in question is set to a hanging lantern, however, when I try

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ soul_lantern 1
```

the block is set to a normal soul lantern rather than a hanging one. Is this a bug, or is there a way to `/setblock` a hanging soul lantern that I'm missing? Or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ### Update
>
> This bug has been fixed. The issue should no longer be present.

This is a [confirmed, unresolved bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-89609). Unless you can find an add-on that will work around this issue, there's not much you can do to fix it now.

If you believe that this is an important issue that should be fixed, consider voting for the issue using the link above, or start watching it so that you will be notified when updates occur.

Answer (score -2):

I found this on another page - I don't remember exactly but it is a tag called [hanging:1]. If I find which page I originally found it on I will leave a link

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ soul_lantern[hanging=1]
```

This bit of code should work, I will edit it as need be.

Comment: thanks for your answer, do tags like [hanging:1] work on Bedrock Edition? I thought that was just for Java edition? Sorry, I should have clarified when I posted my question, I’ve updated it now.

Comment: @DM01131 No, the `[hanging=1]` does not work on Bedrock Edition.

Comment: In Java Edition, it's `[hanging=1]`, not `[hanging:1]`

Comment: wouldn't it be curly braces too even if this was java?